# samba web client - setup connection in php script

Tags: php, samba

I have to establish connection with `Samba` server from my `php` script in order to download some files into my local server.

Actually its first time I have heard of something like `Samba` so I Tried to look for a opensource code that I could make use of.

Here it is what I have found: [First class - smbclient.php](http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/34-web/66-accessing-smb-servers-with-php) and I tried code posted on the page:

```
<?php

require_once ('smbclient.php');

$smbc = new smbclient ('//10.0.1.1/example', 'exampleuser', 'examplepassword');

if (!$smbc->get ('path/to/desired/file.txt', '/tmp/localfile.txt'))
{
    print "Failed to retrieve file:\n";
    print join ("\n", $smbc->get_last_stdout());
}
else
{
    print "Transferred file successfully.";
}

?>
```

Adjusting it into my needs ( server, user, password),  all i got is

```
Failed to retrieve file: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method smbclient::get_last_stdout()
```

Then I found out about `smbwebclient.php` project which looks awesome and can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smbwebclient/).

And this class looks good but the problem is that I have no idea how to use it. Can anyone post it example connection or link  to tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get files from a samba server, you can try to use a smb wrapper, like the one [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/20566.html) but changing the deprecated splits with explodes. Then you can include your php file using this code:

```
include_once('smb.php');
include( 'smb://user:password@server/folder/file.php');
```

Comment: Sorry to hop onto such and old answer, I'm using the class you linked and am connecting to my share, however when I use file_get_contents for a file I'm getting the error `url_stat(): dir failed for path`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Reviving old thread but I think I found the solution, the code must have changed since the pot was made on the blog:

```
print join ("\n", $smbc->get_last_stdout());
```

should now be

```
print join ("\n", $smbc->get_last_cmd_stdout());
```